# updating multiple attributes python

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have a class `Test` that has attributes `Test.att1`, `Test.att2`, ... , `Test.att10`. I have a method `Test.update()` that computes ten new values `vals = [v1, v2, ... , v10]`. I'd like to update `Test`'s attributes in a single for loop.

I envision something like looping through the list `mylist = [self.att1, self.att2, ... , self.att10]` within the `Test` class and setting values per `vals` but this didn't seem to work. What can I do instead / what's the best way to update multiple attributes without using a `self.att1, self.att2, self.att3 = v1, v2, v3` structure?

EDIT: I'm specifically asking because I am doing something like:

```
a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 = self.update()
self.a1 = pd.concat([self.a1, a1]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
self.a2 = pd.concat([self.a2, a2]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
self.a3 = pd.concat([self.a3, a3]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
self.a4 = pd.concat([self.a4, a4]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
self.a5 = pd.concat([self.a5, a5]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

and am currently using
One backwards way I ended up doing this was:

```
def update(self):
    dfs = [self.att1, self.att2, ..., self.att10]
    dfs = [pd.concat([dfs[i], vals[i]]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True) \
                for i in range(len(dfs))]
    [self.att1, self.att2, ..., self.att10] = dfs
```

but at seeking a better way

Comment: Why don't you write a method which will take the list and update the attributes? it will be easier for you in that way.

Comment: They all share a similar structure along the lines of `pd.concat([self.att1,df]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)` so I was wondering how to only write once and avoid writing 10 times...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setattr` in combinatin with `hasattr` to update and add attributes to the target object.

```
attrs = [a for a in dir(Test) if a.startswith('attr') and 'no_update' not in a]

### To update existing attrs ###
new_vals = [...]
for a, v in zip(attrs, new_vals):
    if hasattr(Test, a):
        setattr(Test, a, v)

### To add new attrs ###
new_vals = [...]
start = int(attrs[-1][4:]) + 1 # the number the new attrs should start at
new_attrs = ['attr%d' % n for n in range(start, start+len(new_vals))] # if start==4 and len(new_vals)==3: return ['attr5', 'attr6', 'attr7']
for a, v in zip(new_attrs, new_vals):
    setattr(Test, a, v)
```

These can also be combined to allow updating existing attrs and setting new ones if need be.

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to append `v` to attribute `a` as per my update? Is this still a clean way of doing it?

Comment: By that do you mean concatenating the new and old attr value? If so, you can `get` the attr just like you can `set` and check if it `has` it like so: `setattr(Test, a, getattr(Test, a) + v)`

Comment: Basically these attributes are pandas DataFrames, and I want to add new lines to an existing 10 or so DataFrames which I have as attributes of `Test`, but I also have other attributes `att_no_update1`, ... `att_no_update10` that I don't want to update

Comment: @jjjjjj I have no experience with `pandas` and have no idea what a `DataFrame` is. Regardless, I think I understand what you want and have updated my answer accordingly